# Best practice to secure administrative fields in REST

Tags: angularjs, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

lets say i a MCV Rest Controller to update my Account document in mongo db.

Account.class

```
public class Account extends Credentials {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String email;
private String password;
private Boolean admin;
private String street;
private String postalcode;
private String city;
private String country;
private String phone;
private String birthday;
private String image;
}
```

email, password are fields to be writable only during signup procedure.
admin is a field only to be writable by administrators.

The rest of the fields can be updated by an "edit account" html UI.

Providing a RESTfull method like this will give all normal users access to all fields:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upsert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Account> upsert(@RequestBody Account acc) throws Exception {
        Provider entity = providerRepository.save(acc);
        return new ResponseEntity<Account>(entity, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

If i flag the "special" fields with @JsonProperty for read access only then the above update will remove them from the db during save operation.

What is the best way to separate the "special" fields from the "normal" fields?

Comment: Create new endpoints with specific view models for each. One for admin creation, filter users (Spring Security). One for signup which will consume all fields (except admin) and one for viewing data which won't have email, password fields.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with view models?

Comment: For example create Account pojo which will have: all fields except admin. ```public ResponseEntity<Account> upsert(@RequestBody AccountSignUp acc)```

Comment: And where do i store the admin related fields? Do you mean i need to double my Account pojo for each view type?

Comment: No, you could do AdminAccount which would extend Account and would declare ```boolean admin``` field

Comment: that should work...thanks!

Comment: hmm...one more thing: how do i story AdminAccount and Account then into the same collection in mongos db using  a spring data repository? Is is possible to setup public interface AccountRepository extends MongoRepository<Account, String> and store AdminAccount into it?